# static variables in a template class c++

Tags: c++, templates, static-members

So, I'm pretty new in the generic programmation and I started the following :

```
template<class T>
class A
{
public:
  static int m;
}

template<class T>
int A<T>::m;

int main()
{
  A::m = 3; //Cannot compile of course !!
  return 1
}
```

The idea being to have a member variable that could be shared by all the instances of A, no matter what T we have.

Would there be any way of doing this or do I have to use a global variable instead ?

Comment: A static member variable is *pretty damn close* to a global variable.

Comment: To share a static member variable amongst all instances, you'll need to put it in a base class common for all of them.

Comment: a `Foo<T>` and a `Foo<U>` are completely unrelated types.  There is no way to share a static variable between them as they are different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Members of class templates are never shared between specializations of the class template. You should consider a class template to be just that: A template to create classes of similar structure based on different types. For each type `T` the specialization `A<T>` is an independent class. The resulting classes are not otherwise related in any way.

If you want to have multiple classes share a static data member, you can put the member in a base class:

```
struct ABase
{
  static int m;
};

template<class T>
struct A : ABase
{
};

int ABase::m;

int main()
{
  A<int>::m = 3;
  return A<double>::m; // will return 3
}
```

You still need to specify a type for the template argument though when accessing the member through `A`, because `A` itself is not a class that has members at all, it is just a template of which specializations may or may not have the `m` member inherited from a base. In particular you could add *partial specializations* or *explicit (full) specializations* of `A` which override the definition of `A<T>` for some types of `T`, so that `A<T>::m` is *not* `ABase::m` any longer.

Also make sure that this really logically makes sense for your use case. Again, specializations of a class template are as such unrelated types.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed !
But could'nt I do in the main ABase::m = 3 ?

Comment: @Cook Yes of course, that also works.